# Dual boot without partitioning

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I occasionally use a VM for experimentation, knowing that I can safely trash the OS without affecting my day to day Windows installation. My PC isn't really up to running the VM though.

WUBI solves the problem partially as it allows me to boot into an Ubuntu installation that is stored on a filesystem entirely within an NTFS file. It runs natively and is completely distinct from my primary Windows installation but didn't require me to partition my drive.

Is it possible to dual boot any other operating systems in this fashion? Ideally I'd like to run a second instance of XP from a file within my main XP installation "WUBI style", instead of inside a VM.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at doing this on Windows 7. It allows you to boot off a VHD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.

- Linux mint ships with Mint4Win which is similar to wubi and allows you to install mint within windows the same way.
- [Topologilinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologilinux) is another distribution that is designed to run within windows. It uses coLinux to run within windows.
- Another program called Instlux also supports openSuse.
- [BEeN GRUBed](http://grubed.sourceforge.net/) also looks awesome and claims it installs 'any OS within windows'. I'm yet to try this one, though.

  Hope this was helpful :-)